# Server IP is detected as user IP

Tags: nginx, ip

the server IP of mine is `***.***.***.234`. For SSL, I needed to add another IP `***.***.***.235`. This is a vps and the IP address was added by a friend.

The problem is: when someone submit comments (WordPress), the user IP is detected as `***.***.***.235`, which is the server ip, not the users and thats really a problem. How this can be solved?

The VPS is running on Cent OS and Nginx.

**Update: VHOST entry**

```
server {
     error_log /var/log/nginx/vhost-error_log warn;
     listen ***.***.***.235:80;
     server_name example.com www.example.com;
     access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com-bytes_log bytes_log;
     access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com combined;
     root /home/tareq/public_html;

     location / {
          location ~.*\.(3gp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|html|htm|txt|js|css|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso)$ {
               expires 1d;
               try_files $uri @backend;
          }

          error_page 405 = @backend;
          add_header X-Cache "HIT from Backend";
          proxy_pass http://***.***.***.235:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
     }

     location @backend {
          internal;
          proxy_pass http://***.***.***.235:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
     }

     location ~ .*\.(php|jsp|cgi|pl|py)?$ {
          proxy_pass http://***.***.***.235:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
     }

     location ~ /\.ht {
          deny all;
     }
}
```

Comment: What software is acting as the SSL endpoint?

Comment: And what do you have running on port 8081?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, visiting 8081 port I am also seeing the site homepage.

Comment: Didn't you set this up? If you don't even know what you have running on your server, you should probably find out, first.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like nginx is not configured to pass client address to Apache.
You will want to alter your nginx configuration file(s) to include the following:

```
server{
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:PORT;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

The final step is to install mod_rpaf for Apache. This module allows you to set the value of the remote address when using a proxy. If you haven’t already got the module installed (try “a2enmod rpaf” to find out), you can install it via apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-rpaf
```

Although you may be retrieving the correct IP addresses now, you’ll want to ensure the module is configured correctly. My Apache configuration file has the following code just below all my other ’s:

```
# The following lines allow client IP to be passed from Nginx to Apache
<IfModule mod_rpaf.c>
    RPAFenable On
    RPAFsethostname On
    RPAFproxy_ips 127.0.0.1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: He said he was running nginx, not apache.

Comment: Yes, it's nginx, not apache. I've updated with my vhost entry

Comment: True,  but where is he sending his dynamic content on port 8081?